# How to customise email transports

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

As I understood Meteor internally uses nodemailer to send emails and creates the corresponding transport based on the defined MAIL_URL environment property.

We have implemented an EmailSenderService which creates several different nodemailer transports. It uses the account settings defined as settings for production mode and a hardcoded ethereal account for development mode.

I wonder if and how it is possible to change the internal Meteor email handling to use our application specific EmailSenderService to send all kind of emails especially the ones send via the account-password package (e.g. enrollment- and forgot-password-emails). My idea is to redirect the calls to the central Email.send function to our EmailSenderService instead of calling the Meteor internal logic.

Thank you for thinking along and any upcoming ideas and hints...

Comment: You can custom Email.send-command like Email.send = function(....) {....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options:

#### 1. Monkeypatch `Email.send`

As @iiro says, you can just monkey patch the `Email` module by replacing the `send` method with your own.

```
Email.send = function (options) {
    return EmailSenderService.send(options);
}
```

#### 2. Replace the `email` package with a local version

If Meteor finds a package of the same name in the `packages/` directory of your project, it will use that one over it's own implementation. [Documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#overriding-atmosphere-packages)

#### <strike>3. Use undocumented features to hook into `Email.send`</strike>

**EDIT:** I didn't see that `EmailTest` isn't exported. So this only works by making a local copy like in option 2.

Looking at the [source of the email package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/efc8a3525db6067bf1d381c033c6ac937c15d631/packages/email/email.js#L145), there's a hook which is run at the start of `Email.send` and allows you to prevent the default execution by returning false. You could use this like so:

```
EmailTest.hookSend(function (options) {
   EmailSenderService.send(options)
   return false; // To stop default sending behaviour
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I like the 'hookSend' variant and will use it for my purposes as described.